# Show $\lim \limits_{t \to \infty} x(t) = 0$ exponentially for any $x(0)\in \mathbb{R}^n$ if $\lim \limits_{t \to \infty} u(t) = 0$ exponentially.

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory, linear-control

I'd like to ask a question about the controllability of a linear system. Any help would be appreciated.
$$$$Given a vector $x(t)\in \mathbb{R}^n$ defined over [$0$, $\infty$), we say $x(t)$ converge to zero exponentially as $t→+\infty$, or $\lim \limits_{t \to \infty} x(t) = 0$ exponentially, if there exist two positive constants $\alpha > 0$ and $\gamma > 0$ such that
$||x(t)|| \leq\alpha||x(0)||e^{-\gamma t}$

Consider the following state equation:
$\dot x = Ax + Bu$,
with $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n{\times}n}$ Hurwitz.
Show that $\lim \limits_{t \to \infty} x(t) = 0$ exponentially for any $x(0)\in \mathbb{R}^n$ if $\lim \limits_{t \to \infty} u(t) = 0$ exponentially.
$$$$ The $x(t)$ can be represented by $x(t) = e^{At}x(0)+ \int_0^t e^{A(t-\tau)}Bu(t)\,d\tau. $ But I cannot reach the mathmetical proof to this question.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Hint: check the proof of ISS for linear systems

Comment: This isn't a full proof but should at least give you some intuition and partial proof for certain edge cases. Namely, consider $u(t)$ such that $\dot{u}(t)=F\,u(t)$ with $F$ also Hurwitz. So the combined system, with state $\begin{bmatrix}x^\top & u^\top\end{bmatrix}^\top$, can be characterized by the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}A & B \\ 0 & F\end{bmatrix}$$ which can also be shown to be Hurwitz, due to the upper triangular block structure.

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is Hurwitz stable, then there exist $\alpha_0,\alpha>0$ such that $||e^{At}||\le\alpha_0 e^{-\alpha t}$ for all $t\ge0$. Moreover, since $u(t)$ converges to zero exponentially fast, then there exist $\beta_0,\beta>0$ such that $||u(t)||\le\beta_0 e^{-\beta t}$ for all $t\ge0$. Let also $M>0$, such that $||B||\le M$.

So, from triangle inequality we have that

$$||x(t)||\le ||e^{At}x(0)||+\left|\left|\int_0^t e^{A(t-\tau)}Bu(\tau)d\tau\right|\right|.$$

We have that $||e^{At}x(0)||\le ||e^{At}||\cdot||x(0)||\le \alpha_0 e^{-\alpha t}||x(0)||\to0$ exponentially.

Similarly, we have that

$\left|\left|\int_0^t e^{A(t-\tau)}Bu(\tau)d\tau\right|\right|\le \int_0^t \left|\left|e^{A(t-\tau)}Bu(\tau)\right|\right|d\tau\le M\alpha_0\beta_0\int_0^te^{-\alpha(t-\tau)-\beta\tau}d\tau=\dfrac{M\alpha_0\beta_0}{\alpha-\beta}(e^{-\beta t}-e^{-\alpha t})\to0$ exponentially.

This shows that $||x(t)||$ converges to zero exponentially fast.